# Image i18n in JSF2

Tags: java, jsf, internationalization, jsf-2

I am trying to localize images in JSF, and I want the user to be able to set their locale on my site.  This I am doing by a call to

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(_locale);
```

which works great, with one exception:

```
<h:graphicImage library="images" name="pic.gif" />
```

uses the `Accept-Language` sent in the browser's request to determine which locale to use.  I can work around this by placing a locale string in each `.properties` file and referencing images by

```
<h:graphicImage library="#{resource.locale}/images" name="pic.gif" />
```

but then there is no fall-back for individual images, so I have to have a copy of every image, whether it is different or not, in every locale's directory.  This is quite cumbersome, given that I support 9 locales and probably more in the future.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Currently I'm looking into "decorating" ViewHandler to override the [public Locale calculateLocale(FacesContext context)] method using the ViewHandlerWrapper class. This looks like a very promising solution, will update when I have done it

Comment: Overriding ViewHandler worked for getting the locale from the correct place, however, image fallback is still an issue - will be using a different library for non-localized images.  Will post full configuration when the implementation is finished.

Comment: See my remark to BalusC below.

Comment: @theFunKyEngineer did you ever got this working? I'm having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting issue. There is however no builtin support for this, not by JSF nor by remnant of Java EE. Your best bet is to create a `Servlet` which knows about the fallback locale and thus basically does the following test:

```
if (getServletContext().getResource(request.getPathInfo()) == null) {
    // Display fallback image instead.
}
```

You could eventually do this by a custom JSF component which does the same check.

Comment: BalusC is indeed the JSF Grand Master, but there is actually very nice built-in support for this in JSF 2. Please read the 3-part series: http://technology-for-human.blogspot.com/2010/10/jsf-20-new-featuers-part-1-of-3.html http://technology-for-human.blogspot.com/2010/10/jsf-20-new-features-part-2-of-3.html http://technology-for-human.blogspot.com/2010/10/jsf-20-new-features-part-3-of-3.html .... especially article number 2.

Comment: @rapt: Please re-read the question. OP is already aware of that. It's just insufficiently suited to OP's particular requirement.

Comment: I do not think OP is aware of this. He is trying to prefix the image path with a string that will correspond to the localized image folder. However in the article they do it without prefixing. The framework does it automatically. It also provides automatic fall-back to a default language.